# How to get vector $\vec{v}$ and on matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have a surjective matrix such that

$$A * V = A * [1,1,1]$$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

I need to find V that is of shape (3,).

This is what I did so far

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6\\4\\?\end{bmatrix}$$

I used a value of 2 for the `?`

So

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6\\4\\2\end{bmatrix}$$

Solving this got me

$$v_1 + 2v_2 + 3v_3 = 6$$
$$2v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = 4$$
$$v_3 = 2$$

which implies

$$v_1 = -2, v_2 = 6, v_3 = 2$$

But apparently, this is wrong. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you make $A$ square?

Comment: And isn't one acceptable $V$ just $[1,1,1]$ by definition?

Comment: I cant use [1,1,1]. I need to find a different value that satisfies the equation

Comment: OK, fine.  Where did the $[6,4,?]$ come from?

Comment: Because Av = A * [1,1,1], If you calculate that you get [6,4] But because v is of shape (3,) I need the other value for the matrix. That is why I added the third row to A and put a question mark for the RHS

Comment: Got it.  Note that there is no need for the third positions.  If $A$ is $2 \times 3$ and $V$ is a 3-component column vector, then the result is a 2-component column vector.  Putting in the mysterious $2$ for the ?-spot is unnecessary and likely the source of your problem.

Comment: To add:  otherwise, your technique is right.  You get a linear system from your constraints, so you can solve that system and find all such solutions.

Comment: I need v to be of shape (3,). That is why I add the extra row

Comment: $V$ will be of shape 3.  The output will NOT.  Review how matrix multiplication works.

Comment: Also, all this background stuff would be best included in the body of the question and help prevent its closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[1 2 3][v1] = [1 2 3][1] = [6]
[2 2 1][v2]   [2 1 1][1]   [4]
       [v3]          [1]

v1+2v2+3v3=6 (1)
2v1+v2+v3=4  (2)

From (2): v3=4-v2-2v1

Plug into (1): v1+2v2+12-3v2-6v1=6
v2=-5v1+6

Plug back in (2): v3=4+5v1-6-2v1
v3=-2+3v1

One possible answer is:
Set v1=2
v2=-4
v3=4

All possible answers of the form:
[0 ] + [1 ]
[6 ]   [-5]x
[-2]   [3 ]
```